# Third Party Java 8 Program Running in Java 11 vs Java 8?

Tags: java

If a vendor provides you with a program written for Java 8, is there any security advantage of running that program in the latest OpenJDK build of Java 11 instead of the latest OpenJDK build of Java 8?

Comment: Answering this question in general is very complicated as a lot of improvements have been back ported to Java 8. Besides that in my opinion Java 11 has more advantages on functional level. But make sure to check the support period of your OpenJDK distribution as for a lot of them the EOL date of Java 11 is often earlier than the EOL date of Java 8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: This seems to be a garbage question. Should we delete it?

Comment: I would no say so. There are security improvements in Java 11 like by default unlimited strength crypto policy and TLS 1.3 support. The problem is just that those features have already been backported to Java 8. So the question is are there any additional security improvements in Java 11.

Comment: @Robert - Did you mean to say, "I would no say so."?  Perhaps you meant "I would not say so"?  I will be deleting this comment very soon.